# Internal hard drive can see files but not copy them

Tags: repair

I had Windows installed on that drive before but when I forced a restart directly from my computer the drive wasn't accessible from the bootloader. What I am trying to do is (now that I have installed Windows on a different hard drive) copy the files I had on the first hard drive to the new one, or at least execute them.

Problem: When I access the hard drive where I have the files and I am able to see them (all the files have the same names as before and are in the same place) but when I try to copy them to the new drive it says "Can not find file..." althought I see it there.

Somebody know how cn I address this without risk of losing the files?
I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: It sounds like you have already lost the files.  It sounds like the drive with the data has already failed, while the filesystem is intact, the actual data for the files is gone.  The filesystem would only be a very small chunk of data on the hdd.

Comment: Is that is 90% sure? No possibility to recover my files? I will take my time and try at any hope. Alternatively, I understand what you mean but there is no possibility this could be for example rebuilt with data recovery programs? From what I know about this programs, usually they recover the files but on a random order with different names which makes a 3TB drive with lots of little files imposible to organize as before, but since I have the names of the files, could it be possible to recover them and then attach the names automatically or similar (without using 100 hours to do it manually.

Comment: What you describe inicates the data is gone.  While some of it might recoverable, you are going to have to use tools to do so, simply trying to copy and paste the data wont work if thats the case.  Also don't restore the data to the drive your trying to recover.

Comment: Try using the command prompt and possibly xcopy to move the files.  You may also need to use diskmgmt.msc to ensure that Windows correctly recognizes the partitions.

Comment: I have checked and just noticed, Disk Management doesn't recognize the partitions correctly however I can see the names of all the files from Windows Explorer. Never happened to me before this way.

Comment: It appears as Disk 0, Unkown, not initialized on Disk Management. Its drive E on Windows Explorer surprisingly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears that your drive has some serious issues. The list of files and folders is kept in a catalogue separate to the data which is why you can see one but cant access the other.

As Ramhound states, you would need to use disk recovery tools to recover the data. Unfortunately, most of those are not free. So it may simply be cheaper to recover from a backup assuming you have one.

Of course, if you don't have a backup and any of the data is critical to you, spending some money might be acceptable. The problem is that there are no guarantees when it comes to data recovery.

I've been in IT long enough to want to have some really good tools to hand and the best one I've used for disk issues is Spinrite from grc.com. Unfortunately, it isn't cheap at around USD90. It is very good at recovering data from dying disks though.

Comment: I just tried spinrite and it says first boot sector is unreadable, I remember sth like that happening before and was able to solve it but don't remember exactly how I did it and it got to my nerves knowing I could screw it up foreever if I did it wrong.

Comment: If spinrite can't make sense of it, it is very likely gone beyond hope I'm afraid. I'd ask on the grc forum though to see if anyone has any ideas. You could of course try some other tools if you have access to them, you never know.